# Connect to 2 different MartenDB datastores with ASP.Net Core

Tags: marten

When setting up a MartenDB datastore in ASP.Net Core, you normally put code like this in your Startup.cs:

```
services.AddMarten(o =>
{
    o.Connection(configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDatabase"));
    o.AutoCreateSchemaObjects = AutoCreate.All;
    o.Serializer(new JsonNetSerializer { EnumStorage = EnumStorage.AsString });
});
```

This allows you to then inject IDocumentSession and IDocumentStore into your various classes for working with that database.

Now what do you do if you have to connect to a second database? I looked at the [ISessionFactory](https://martendb.io/documentation/integration/) but it is not apparent that you can change the connection string from here. Do you need to manually create and register a new DocumentStore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, I wound up creating a custom DocumentStore and ISessionFactory for each database I wanted to connect to, and then injecting the custom SessionFactory.

Here's the code (only showing one instance of each class for the sake of brevity. Just replace `Db1` with `Db2` for the second version of each class):

The custom DocumentStore:

```
public class Db1Store : DocumentStore
{
    public Db1Store(StoreOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

The custom SessionFactory:

```
public class Db1SessionFactory : ISessionFactory
{
    private readonly Db1Store store;

    public Db1SessionFactory(Db1Store store)
    {
        this.store = store;
    }

    public IQuerySession QuerySession()
    {
        return store.QuerySession();
    }

    public IDocumentSession OpenSession()
    {
        return store.OpenSession();
    }
}
```

The service registration (this replaces the `services.AddMarten` call):

```
  services.AddSingleton(p =>
  {
      var options = new StoreOptions();
      options.Connection(configuration.GetConnectionString("DB1"));
      options.AutoCreateSchemaObjects = AutoCreate.All;
      options.Serializer(new JsonNetSerializer { EnumStorage = EnumStorage.AsString });
      return new Db1Store(options);
  });
  
  services.AddSingleton<Db1SessionFactory>();
```

Then you inject the Db1SessionFactory instance into your class, and run a query like this:

```
var result = await db1SessionFactory.QuerySession().Query<MyAwesomeTable>().ToListAsync();
```

---

**Downsides**:

- I would prefer to inject the QuerySession or DocumentSession, but I can't see a way to do that without moving to Autofac or a similar DI Container that supports named instances.
- I am not sure what downsides there will be creating these QuerySession/DocumentSessions in this manner. It may be a bad tradeoff.